# Predicate for comparing the month component of a Core Data date attribute

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have a Core Data entity which has a date attribute. I would like to write a predicate to extract all dates within a specific month, e.g. July, irrespective of year. How can this be achieved? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a new method on your entity, which we'll call `monthOfDate`.  This method simply uses `[self dateAttribute]` and `NSDateComponents` to extract what the month of the date is.

Then you can write a predicate that does:

```
//assuming 1-based month indexing
NSPredicate * julyEntities = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"monthOfDate = 7"];
```

The trick here is realizing that the left keypath of your predicate will result in a method invocation.  So if you set the left keypath to "monthOfDate", it will end up invoking your `monthOfDate` method and using the return value of the method as the comparison value in the predicate.  Neat!

Comment: Realize that this will only work against data that has already been loaded into memory.  To do the same thing for data not yet fetched you will need to de-normalize your data and store that value in the database.

Answer (score 0):

can't comment yet so asking this way.

How did you end up implementing this? I tried adding a method in the managed object class but once the predicate fires it says it can't find the keypath monthOfDate?

Updated with both files:

.h file:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSNumber *monthOfDate;
-(NSNumber *)monthOfDate;
```

.m file:

```
@synthesize monthOfDate;

-(NSNumber *) monthOfDate
{
NSDate *date = [self start];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]components: NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:date];
NSNumber *month = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[components month]];
return month;
}
```

**Update 2**

The code above is in the auto-generated Event class (NSmanaged object). I might move my custom code to a category later but so far no model revisions are necessary.

Below is the FetchedResultsController (in a uiviewcontroller class) setup with mentioned predicate:

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortfix = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortfix,nil]];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"client == %@ AND monthOfDate = %d", clientMO,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:6]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];


NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =

[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:sectionKeyPathProperty
                                               cacheName:nil];

//sectionKeyPathProperty is a variable that let's me choose one of multiple transient properties I have created for creating relevant sections.

self.fetchedResultsControllerClient = theFetchedResultsController;
_fetchedResultsControllerClient.delegate = self;

return _fetchedResultsControllerClient;
```

Comment: Did you put your property declaration in your header file (.h)?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the code above to what I have now. Just tried a lot of stuff, changed it to an NSNumber as well. Still the same 'keypath monthOfDate not found in entity' error. I guess I could just save some extra attributes to my tables and do lots of comparisons but I've got a feeling this should work (and smoothly if it does) so I really want to try and get it to work :)

Comment: Please show your code where you set up your fetchRequest and let me know what the name of the class is in which you have created the "monthOfDate" method

Comment: Apologies, took some time to the wrap my head around the way I eventually implemented this. This will only work once all your MO has been loaded into memory (i.e.) after the base object has been fetched. As this will not be practical for your scenario, you need to create a monthOfDate field in your table schema and populate it when you first create/save the MO.

Comment: No no, thank you for replying to a 4yo thread! :) Ahh! That's what Marcus S. Zarra meant in his comment.  Would've been great if it could do this! I'll create a new attribute for it then. Although I figure, that I could probably loop through the FRC's results and then call that method from [EventMO.timeStamp monthOfDate] as well if I needed it for some small alterations. I'll see what turns out to be the most intuitive. Thanks again Run Loop!

Comment: pleasure! One tip - try and create [NSCalendar currentCalendar] only once in your project, e.g. in your AppDelegate as it is an expensive call.