# Filter data from coredata using year and month of the date attribute

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

Say I have coredata entity with date and title. I know we can filter data from core data using  NSPredicate. But I want to filter data based on month and year of the date attribute. Is it possible via NSpredicate? If so how to do?

Comment: Did you see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935542/predicate-for-comparing-the-month-component-of-a-core-data-date-attribute?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, Sorry I didn't see that